# How to check in real time if a user exists in a JavaScript object through an input element (raw js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, livesearch

I'm quite new to JS and am trying to check if a user or any value exists in a JavaScript object in real time, the goal is to implement this in Firebase in order to prevent user registration if that username has already been taken but I am doing it locally first because Im learning. This is what I have so far.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
btn.disabled = false

let users = [
    {
        uname: "mark"
    },
    {
        uname: "sarah"
    },
    {
    ...others uname
    }
]

input.addEventListener('input', () => {

    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "")
    check(input.value)
    
})

function check(val) {

    users.forEach((item) => {
        let uname = item.uname

        if (uname.indexOf(val) > -1 && uname === val) {
            console.log('That user name has been taken')
            btn.disabled = true
        } else {
            console.log('Ok')
            btn.disabled = false
        }
    })
}
```

The problem with that is when I typed in the input element Im getting both the if and else triggered and while (val) matches some key/value pairs the others won't and then I am able to use whatever username Im typing which is not what I want.

How can I solved this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking to see if the username has been found.

```
function isUsernameAvailable (val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var uname = users[i].name;

        if (uname === val) {
            console.log('That user name has been taken')
            btn.disabled = true

            return false; // the username is taken, we can stop checking
        }
    }

    console.log('Ok')
    btn.disabled = false

    return true;
}
```

Also, `forEach` doesn't let you exit the loop early and you don't need to check every user after you found a match (if you find a match).